# Timescale is still 0 but it should be 1 again

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i make an Android Game, with Unity. When you hit an Object you die and the player keeps moving forward so i decided to stop the time. Also i set the Time to 0. Then when i die and hit the restart button, the Time is still 0. Even if i write in the Restart()-Method, Time.timeScale=1f, nothing changes. The Restart Method just build the same level again.

Can someone help me please!

Here is when the Player collides to an Object with the Tag "Obstacle":

```
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {

        if (collision.collider.tag == "Obstacle")
        {

            Time.timeScale = 0f;

            FindObjectOfType<GameManager>().DeathCanvas();

        }
```

Then the Death Canvas pop up and you can tap "Restart". This is the Restart-Method in the Gamemanager:

```
public void Restart ()
    {
        Time.timeScale = 1f;
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
    }
```

Comment: You didn't give enough information, could you please show the code where you're setting Time.timeScale to 0 and where you're calling the Restart Method

Comment: sorry, i edited my question. I hope this is enough information.

Comment: If I remember correctly timescale at zero will prevent certain actions like buttons from working. Can you put a log into restart and see if it fires?

Answer (score 0):

OK thanks for the extra information, I don't know how the scene is set up, but from the looks of it, the collision could be being triggered right after the timescale is reset, moving it right back to 0. It's generally not a good practice to handle it like this.

I would suggest that you do not stop the game using timeScale. A much better way to stop the player without messing with time is to have a bool on the player object for "isRunning" and only run when that bool is set to true. Then, when you die, just set it to false and after restarting set it to true again.

This way you avoid some bugs that can be caused by a zero timescale.

If you just want to make your current solution work,
1) Search your entire project for Time.timeScale just to make sure it's not being modified elsewhere
2) Don't set timeScale to 0 more than once. Declare a private bool called hasDied and set it to true as soon as the player dies. Then check for it before setting the time scale again. The bool will reset when the scene is reloaded. Example:

```
private bool hasDied = false;
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {

        if (!hasDied && collision.collider.tag == "Obstacle")
        {
            hasDied = true;
            Time.timeScale = 0f;

            FindObjectOfType<GameManager>().DeathCanvas();

        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use something like

```
Time.timeScale = 0.000001f;
```

Don't set it to exactly zero, this might help.